# Can someone please explain this function to me

Tags: php

I am currently studying how to use the regexp searching function.Then i came across this.i have tried for days to get but i could not.i will appreciate if someone can break it down for me.

```
<?php

preg_match("#<<(.*)>>#ismU", $object, $options));

?>
```

Comment: Can you specify value of `$object` and output what you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

the stuff between the # is the pattern to match against

the ismU at the end is  the modifiers so 
i = case insensitive
s = matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded 
m = treats the subject string as consisting of a single "line" of characters even if it actually contains several newlines
U = sets the regex to be non greedy by default

`<<(.*)>>` is the actual pattern its self which I believe pulls out everything in the input text between << >>

So if you passed a text string `this is some <<strong>>test</strong> code` to the match it would return an array containing strong in it as strong is inside the << >> brackets

Comment: If you're going to -1 the answer perhaps a reason why would be useful so I can improve answers in future?

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation